# Multiple models validation in the same View - Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm looking for a strategy to validate the uniqueness of the keys of four models that have relationships with each other before finally being able to save them in the database.

In other words, I would like to check the uniqueness of the keys so that there is no inconsistency in the database when using the `Model.save()` method, and only use it when all the unique keys are really unique.

Following the view below as an example, the fields *cnpj*, *address*, and *number* respectively in `LegalPerson`, `Email` and `Phone`, must be unique.

```
class StoreRegistrationView(View):
    '''
    Classe responsavel pelo cadastro de lojas
    '''
    def post(self, request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            form = StoreForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                lp = LegalPerson(
                    cnpj = form.cleaned_data['cnpj'],
                    corporate_name = form.cleaned_data['corporate_name'],
                    fantasy_name = form.cleaned_data['fantasy_name'],
                    state_inscription = form.cleaned_data['state_inscription'],
                    municipal_inscription = form.cleaned_data['municipal_inscription'],
                    )

                lp.save()

                address = Address(
                    street = form.cleaned_data['street'],
                    neighborhood = form.cleaned_data['neighborhood'],
                    number = form.cleaned_data['number'],
                    complement = form.cleaned_data['complement'],
                    city = form.cleaned_data['city'],
                    estate = form.cleaned_data['estate'],
                    country = 'Brasil',
                    cep = form.cleaned_data['cep'],
                    latitude = form.cleaned_data['latitude'],
                    longitude = form.cleaned_data['longitude'],
                    person = lp,
                    )

                address.save()

                email = Email(
                    address = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                    person=lp,
                    )

                email.save()

                phone = Phone(
                    number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
                    person=lp,
                    )

                phone.save()

                # Mensagem de sucesso que será disponibilizada para o usuário
                messages.success(request, 'Cadastro de loja efetuado com sucesso.')

                return redirect('importar-produtos')

        messages.warning(request, 'Erro durante o cadastro.')
        context = {
            'store_form': StoreForm(),
                }

        return render(request, 'n3oadmin/store-registration.html', context)
```

I've been researching, and found that models in django have some validating methods like `Model.full_clean()`, `Model.clean()`, and `Model.validate_unique()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a regular form, you should create multiple model forms.

```
class LegalPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LegalPerson
        fields = [...]

class = AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LegalPerson
        exclude = ['person']
```

Then, use your model forms in your view and template. The model forms will take care of validating unique constraints.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
    legal_person_form = LegalPersonForm(request.POST)

    if address_form.is_valid() and legal_person_form.is_valid():
        person = legal_person_form.save()
        address = address_form.save(commit=False)
        address.person = person
        address.save()

        ...

        return redirect('importar-produtos')
else:
    address_form = AddressForm()
    legal_person_form = LegalPersonForm()

context = {
    'address_form': address_form,
    'legal_person_form': legal_person_form,
}
return render(request, 'n3oadmin/store-registration.html', context)
```

Note you can exclude foreign key fields in the model form. Then, in the view, you can save with `commit=False`, set the foreign key, then save the instance.

Note also that we have only instantiated blank forms `AddressForm()` and `LegalPersonForm` in the `else` block (for GET requests). This means that if the form is valid, you get to see the form errors in the template instead of a blank form.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this here to set a unique field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#unique